# Convert unix time to month number?

Tags: date, unix, lua, unix-timestamp, roblox

Using `os.time` how can I get how many months have passed since the unix epoch (Unix Timestamp)

I just need it for a month ID, so any kind of number would be fine, as long as it changes every month, and it can be reversed to get the actual month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
local function GetMonth(seconds)
    local dayduration,year = 3600*24
    local days={31,0,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31}
    for i=1970,10000 do -- For some reason too lazy to use while
        local yeardays = i%4 == 0 and i%100 ~= 0 and 366 or 365
        local yearduration = dayduration * yeardays
        if yearduration < seconds then
            seconds = seconds - yearduration
        else
            year = i break
        end
    end
    days[2]=(year%4==0) and 29 or 28
    seconds = seconds%(365*24*3600)
    for i=1,12 do
        if seconds>days[i]*dayduration then
            seconds=seconds-days[i]*dayduration
        else
            return --i + year*12  <-- If you want a unique ID
        end
    end
end
```

Currently, it'll give the number 2, since it's February. If you uncomment the code at the end for the unique ID, you'll get 554 instead, meaning we're currently at the 554th month since the epoch.

As Jean-Baptiste Yunès said in his answer's comments, I'm not sure if your sentence:

> NOTE: This is for Lua, but I'm unable to use os.date

meant you have no os.date, or that you don't know how to use it. You have an answer for both cases, you can use the one you need.

Comment: Works perfectly! And yes, I meant I couldn't use os.date

Comment: You might want to check the Free Models for "Data and Time Module", as there are several that have all the things you need.

Answer (score -1):

This may do the trick:

```
print (os.date("*t",os.time())["month"])
```

`os.time()` gives you the current date as a number. `os.date("*t",...)` converts it into a table in which the `month` equals to the number of the month corresponding to the date.

Comment: He clearly stated that he's unable to use os.date _(no idea why, probably a Lua engine like ROBLOX)_

Comment: If think he don't understand how os.date() works. Don't be so rude and let him decide...

Comment: Ah, I thought he meant "There is no os.date" not "I just don't know how to use it"

Comment: Yeah, it's ROBLOX - no os.date @EinsteinK

Comment: You should use `os.time` then

Comment: Right, I assumed "unable" was clear enough, but now I understand your confusion